# Redmiensionar imágenes PHP 5.6

Tags: php, imagen, servidor

Tengo un servidor Debian 9.4 con la versión de PHP 5.6.37. Lo que necesito es saber como puedo re dimensionar imágenes sin la biblioteca GD ya que por motivos que desconozco no me deja instalarla. He intentado que mi proyecto tire de una versión distinta de PHP ya que están instaladas la 5.6, 7.0, 7.1 y 7.2 las cuales al menos la 7.1 y 7.2 son versiones que se suponen que tienen la biblioteca GD incluida en el núcleo, pero por más que intento no hay manera de hacer que tire de ahí mi proyecto. **Entonces estoy intentando buscar como re dimensionar imágenes sin esa biblioteca (GD) en la versión 5.6 de PHP.**

PD: No puedo cambiar la versión de PHP para que todos los proyectos en el servidor tiren por ejemplo de la 7.2 ya que hay código antiguo y dejaría de funcionar algunas funciones por evidentes razones.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Sabes si tu servidor tiene aunque sea `ImageMagick`? De lo contrario te diría que te busques otro proveedor

Comment: *"no me deja instalarla"* ¿Qué o quién?